# C#のdecimal 型のオーバーフロー確認について

Tags: c#

#### 【状況】

- **Price**：商品価格（`decimal`型）　データグリッドに保持。
- **Count**：商品数量（`int`型）　　　テキストボックスにユーザーが入力する
- **Amount**：税込み金額（`decimal`型）

上記の価格**Price**と数量**Count**から税込み金額**Amount**を算出するコンポーネントを作成しています。
現実には起こりにくいと思いますが、
**Price**と**Count**が共に大きい場合、**Amount**が`decimal.MaxValue`を超えるおそれがあります。
これを回避する処理を書き、下記ケースではテストに成功しました。
私のとった手法は、積を一度`double`型で受けて`decimal`型に変換可能か`try~catch`で確認する方法です。

#### 【質問】

[過去の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/6711)にもあるように、
`double`型で金額を計算するのはまずいという認識がありますが、
`decimal`型のオーバーフローを確認する方法として下記は一般に成立しますか？
成立しないような気がするのですが、他に方法も思いつきません。
趣味の範囲ですが、よろしくお願いします。

```
/***** constants *****/
const int TAX_RATE = 10;

/***** input_start *****
(decimal) Price    = 792280000000000000000000000
    (int) Count    = 100
 *****  input_end  *****/


private decimal _amount;
public decimal Amount
{
    get { return _amount; }
    set { amount = value; }
}
private decimal _price;
public decimal Price
{
    get { return _price; }
    set { _price = value; }
}
private decimal _cnt;
public decimal Cnt
{
    get { return _cnt; }
    set
    {
        int Count = value;

        double dTaxAmount = Convert.ToDouble(Convert.ToDouble(Price) * TAX_RATE * 0.01d * Count);
        double dTemp = Convert.ToDouble(Price * Count) + dTaxAmount;

        decimal mTemp = 0;
        try
        {
            mTemp = Convert.ToDecimal(dTemp);
        }
        catch (OverflowException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("注文可能金額を超えています。");
            return;
        }

        decimal mTaxAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(Convert.ToDouble(Price) * TAX_RATE * 0.01d * Count);
        _amount = Convert.ToDecimal(Price * Count) + mTaxAmount;
        _cnt = value;
    }
}
```

#### 【参考】

decimal     ±1.0 × 10^-28 から ±7.9228 × 10^28    28 から 29 桁の数字   16 バイト  System.Decimal
[組み込みの数値変換 (C# リファレンス)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/numeric-conversions)
[浮動小数点数値型 (C# リファレンス)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types)

Comment: 過去質問に評判の良いものを見つけたので追記します。[longの飽和演算を行うアルゴリズム](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/10691)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`checked`ステートメント](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#the-checked-and-unchecked-statements)や[`checked`演算子](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#the-checked-and-unchecked-operators)を使えば`OverflowException`が発生するので悩む必要もないかと。

```
try {
    _amount = checked(Price * (1 + TAX_RATE * 0.01m) * Count);
}
catch (OverflowException) {
    Console.WriteLine("注文可能金額を超えています。");
    return;
}
```

Comment: checkedを使って簡単に確認できました。